# Tensorflow GPU error: ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow

This is the traceback,

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow import contrib
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import layers
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import *
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.initializers import *
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import random_ops
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import versions
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/versions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/eldor4do/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is my .bashrc file,

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64 

PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, cuda7.5 an cudnn 4.0.7, and I have installed tensorflow using pip inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is cuda7.5. As far as I understand, TensorFlow is linked in a way that it only works with cuda7.0. You either need to build it from source, or degrade your local cuda version to 7.0 (as an option, create a docker container and install lower version of cuda there, if you need 7.5 for other purposes).